# Would it be feasible to time channel rebalancing by watching miner fees?

Tags: transaction-fees, lightning-network, ln-channel-balance-management

Is there a way to monitor Bitcoin miners’ fees so one would could calculate the optimum time to perform a circular re-balance thereby minimizing the fees charged?

Comment: Hi Orange Bitcoin, I touched up your question to give a more speaking title and remove salutations. Please feel free to rollback or further edit the question, if you feel that I changed the intent of your post.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. If you run a Lightning node you also have a Bitcoin node which has a history of all transactions. From those one can compute the mining fees of each block (or just look them up in the respective coinbase transaction under the reasonable assumption that the miner claimed all fees).

However, for circular rebalancing the onchain fees are irrelevant as you only care about routing fees. The situation becomes different for peerswaps and the like.

Comment: Hi Murch, Hi Rene, Thank you for your advice. Orange_Bonzo